# Can javascript open a secondary window before the full document is loaded?

Tags: javascript, delay, window.open, immediate-window

I am writing a CGI application which sometimes takes up to one minute to run, but not always.  In the cases I am able to predict the delay, I would like to open another window warning the user of the expected delay.  My first attempt was to have my CGI script add the line

```
    window.onload = function(){window.open('<URL FOR WINDOW WARNING OF DELAY>')}
```

to the javascript code embedded into the html document.  However the warning window is only opened when the html document is fully loaded, which unfortunately only happens after my slow process has finished running.  In other words, too late!

Is it possible to force Javascript to open a secondary window immediately, namely before the current html document is read in full?

Comment: First off, it's much better to just shown an overlay in your current document than to open a new window.  New windows are a pain for the end-user and can be troublesome with popup blockers.  And, secondly, if you describe your situation in more detail, we could probably offer a better solution, but we'd need to know what starts in the browser, what action does the user take that triggers your cgi and what then happens after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it's waiting because you're putting it in the `window.onload` handler, which, well... waits for the entire window (and its resources) to finish loading.

However, even if you do wait for the onload handler, the popup will be blocked by popup blockers. The only safe way to open a window is within a `click` event handler.

The better way would be to put some HTML immediately following the open `<body>` tag and remove it from `window.onload`

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('loader'));
}
```

```css
#loader {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  border: 2px solid firebrick;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
 Please wait while page loads  
</div>

<img src="http://deelay.me/5000/http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg" />

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu convallis leo, a condimentum erat. Integer non blandit ligula, sed pretium ante. Cras convallis consequat lorem, tincidunt vehicula sapien dignissim ut. Fusce lacinia neque eu tortor gravida, a ornare eros mollis. Donec fringilla enim ut auctor iaculis. Fusce sed ipsum iaculis, pretium nunc aliquet, tempor ipsum. Ut ac purus sed massa finibus sollicitudin. Ut finibus sem vitae nibh interdum, et maximus mauris pretium. Sed imperdiet nulla non consequat ultrices. Praesent feugiat velit id lacinia faucibus. Aenean iaculis mi ac cursus tempus. Fusce interdum enim et leo hendrerit sollicitudin. Ut feugiat a tellus ac tincidunt. Integer eget convallis sem. Nullam eget dolor id augue volutpat efficitur. Nam at tortor nec purus cursus ullamcorper at sit amet mauris. Sed tristique, turpis ut commodo dictum, leo est bibendum enim, et convallis nunc nibh nec massa. Ut tempor ipsum sapien, ut aliquam libero volutpat et. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc libero diam, porta a mattis eget, aliquet non urna. Nullam ex nisi, elementum tristique luctus eu, pharetra at leo. Nulla ac vestibulum nisl. Duis facilisis placerat augue non ornare. Proin tempor ultricies semper. Praesent odio dui, maximus nec erat sit amet, efficitur vestibulum metus. Phasellus in diam consequat, rhoncus quam nec, faucibus purus. Nulla nec scelerisque neque. Pellentesque pretium, dolor vel porta egestas, metus ex ullamcorper turpis, ac maximus est ipsum luctus nulla. Integer lobortis sapien id eros gravida maximus. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac volutpat elit, in pulvinar mauris. Aliquam enim est, lacinia id lacus vitae, interdum varius ex. Cras urna tortor, tristique sed nibh ac, vehicula ornare magna. Donec vel semper nisi, imperdiet aliquet diam.  Nullam eget pretium ipsum. Morbi semper at eros ac ornare. Quisque id enim sit amet magna imperdiet tristique ut eget quam. In egestas condimentum nisi vel consectetur. Nunc auctor tellus sed mi malesuada, sed iaculis nisi feugiat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus dictum scelerisque elementum. Nam convallis, risus ac dapibus iaculis, arcu neque pulvinar sapien, sit amet auctor nisi felis quis nunc. Proin mattis metus sed mauris imperdiet, et dictum diam vestibulum. Vivamus ac mattis tortor. Phasellus felis lorem, posuere a magna non, tempus dignissim lacus. Nulla vitae euismod turpis. Mauris a nunc quis ligula placerat pulvinar. Donec et quam vitae orci sodales vulputate at ac risus. Quisque eleifend augue in elit dignissim, et aliquet dui ultricies. Duis eget auctor nunc, ac facilisis velit. Mauris lacus nibh, finibus a blandit sed, hendrerit nec turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin nulla enim, tempor eu augue a, fringilla feugiat arcu. Proin molestie ex sit amet purus laoreet maximus quis in leo. Ut rhoncus metus nisi. Morbi in ipsum vitae erat sodales bibendum. Praesent vitae rhoncus odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In convallis tristique odio. Ut sit amet lorem sed enim tristique tincidunt. Nunc quis dictum tortor.    Vestibulum maximus dui malesuada, bibendum mi sed, finibus nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed semper risus nisi, non lobortis quam luctus a. Curabitur posuere felis eget erat aliquet imperdiet. Vestibulum mollis feugiat sapien quis ultrices. Vivamus quis ipsum eget nibh vehicula interdum sed nec justo. Pellentesque sagittis, lacus ac malesuada elementum, neque risus eleifend quam, at sollicitudin erat libero ac turpis. Vivamus eu lorem ut sapien fringilla facilisis. Mauris facilisis venenatis ex, nec dapibus ligula fringilla quis. Quisque tempus vehicula ante. Sed vel finibus arcu.  Proin in leo at neque pulvinar tincidunt. Morbi efficitur diam nec vulputate interdum. Nunc dapibus felis sollicitudin quam imperdiet sollicitudin. Maecenas eu lacus in sem tempus iaculis. Duis placerat semper nibh, nec malesuada nunc ullamcorper ac. Vestibulum consectetur elit felis, non hendrerit dolor ornare aliquam. Praesent at pretium erat. Duis id velit et velit rutrum efficitur eu ut enim. Phasellus eget molestie nisl, sit amet vulputate turpis. Maecenas id ullamcorper sem.   Aliquam ac quam quis purus pellentesque faucibus ac at tellus. Cras sollicitudin vulputate metus, nec tempus tortor. Donec in venenatis nibh. Vivamus maximus sem leo, nec aliquet quam bibendum in. Curabitur luctus, lectus in tempus pretium, nunc lorem lobortis metus, a mattis lectus odio id ante. Proin viverra sapien id felis vehicula, non condimentum ipsum pulvinar. Fusce vitae nisl dui. Nunc at aliquet ante.In non tellus in turpis malesuada tempor scelerisque eu dui. Vivamus sagittis porttitor dui, at lobortis massa commodo ut. Vestibulum ac elementum diam. Ut in egestas dolor. Aenean in ante elit. Etiam dictum nulla odio, sagittis pretium eros aliquam sit amet. Fusce venenatis hendrerit lacus, vitae semper quam molestie non. Aenean lacinia massa vitae felis ullamcorper auctor. Nulla sapien velit, sagittis ac sapien nec, varius pharetra erat. In ornare, arcu a vestibulum lacinia, lorem est molestie mi, eget dapibus dolor odio a mauris. Sed non nibh risus. Fusce facilisis mauris tristique, imperdiet sem quis, maximus turpis. In sit amet nibh venenatis, egestas dolor quis, sagittis mauris. Sed gravida, ex in gravida aliquet, sem nunc sollicitudin mi, sed vehicula turpis magna nec odio. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed feugiat massa et tempus lacinia. Duis consectetur ac libero nec hendrerit. Vivamus eu fringilla libero, euismod maximus felis. Nulla laoreet viverra magna nec auctor. Etiam dignissim sollicitudin tellus, non semper dui imperdiet vel. Pellentesque enim mi, imperdiet vitae suscipit vel, euismod ut lacus. Aliquam congue faucibus sapien, eu tempus erat aliquet at.   
</p>
```

Comment: Removing a warning is a nice idea, but the problem I have is inserting it.  Any html in the original document will be seen by the user only after the whole page is fully loaded, hence too late.  I would like to give the user something to look at (not necessarily another window) while the original page is loaded.

Comment: @ruy I don't understand what you mean. You can put whatever you want into the warning dialog, just make sure it's the first thing following the open body tag

Comment: Hi @Juan!  Here is a concrete example of a CGI script which I hope will illustrate my question:<br>
<br>
#!/bin/bash<br>
printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n<br>
<body onLoad='alert(\"Please wait: this will take some time to load.\")'><br>
<p> Beginning to load."<br>
sleep 5  # Simulate some lenghty processing<br>
printf "<p> Done! </body>\n"<br>
<br>
How can I warn the user of the expected dalay BEFORE the page is loaded?<br>

Comment: @Ruy Are you even looking at the example I have here (Run code snippet button) ? There's a warning before the page is loaded and it goes away once the page is loaded and I even have a simulated wait in there.

Comment: Hi @Juan!  I am sorry for my oversight.  You can tell I am a beginner both at programing and at dealing with the StackOverflow site.  Now that I understand it, your answer makes perfect sense and has solved my problem!  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flag = true;
var DELAY = 10000;

setTimeout(function () {   
  if (flag == true) window.open('<URL FOR WINDOW WARNING OF DELAY>')
}, DELAY);

window.onload = function(){ flag = false; }
```

The idea is that if your page is not loaded in 10 000 ms, open a new window. But if the page will be loaded faster, it sets `flag = false` and the condition in timeout is not executed.

Comment: I would like to invoke the window.open function immediately, rather than delaying it.